# Casting Object/Dynamic to Anonymous Type

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dynamic, casting, anonymous-types

I have an EF query which returns an anonymous type of several joined tables. I pass this to another function as a dynamic. Is there any way to cast the dynamic to an anonymous type of known anonymous type? If there is a way to do this, I would assume that passing it as an Object is better than a dynamic, is this correct?

```
...
var appts = (from a in dbc.tblAppt join b in dbc.tblApptTypes on a.Type equals b.Type select new {a, b}).ToList();
If (appts.Any())
    ProcessAppts(appts);
}

void ProcessAppts(dynamic appts)
{
    var AnonTypeAppts = appts as (new {tblAppt, tblApptTypes}); // This bit here
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Anonymous types are... anonymous. You can't cast a variable to an anonymous type, like you tried in your code. And preferably you shouldn't pass them around though other methods. They should be kept inside. And you really shouldn't use `dynamic` for this.

I suggest to create a 'real' type which you *can* pass around to another method.

Comment: Ok, I figured that'd be the only solution and was just trying to cut corners. There doesn't seem to be an answer anywhere else, probably because no one else is stupid enough to try it. Thanks.

Comment: @sonnyJim I tend to take the approach that anonymous types are great within the context of a single method, but as soon as someone else needs to care about them, take the time to make a new class definition. But just FYI, given a `dynamic`, you don't need to cast it back. You simply duck-type the members to get to them, `dynamic` and the DLR does the rest. That said, don't do this.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth Normally if I was passing the object to more than one location I would make a proper class, however, this is only used by two methods (one overloaded method) so I know exactly what is going on, the code is well documented to make it clear that it's an anon type with {a,b,c,etc} in it (I'm also a solo dev at the moment but that will probably change in the future). I haven't done anything like this before and I think I'm probably misusing it, given than both you and Patrick have said rewrite it, I will do that.Also I know duck typing, there's no intellisense etc for that though.